# Getting a zero value for a variable that clearly should not be zero

Tags: scilab

I have written the following code to calculate temperature distribution along a fin. For some reason, it keeps calculating certain values as zero, even when they aren't!

```
for t = 0:300:3000
for i = 2:L2
    if i ==2
        A(i)= 0.75*rhocp*DX/DT + 3*k/dx;
        B(i)= k/dx;
        C(i)= 2*k/dx;
        D(i)= 0.75*rhocp*(DX/DT)*T(i);
    elseif i == L2
        A(i)= 0.75*rhocp*DX/DT + 3*k/dx;
        B(i)= 2*k/dx;
        C(i)= k/dx;
        D(i)= 0.75*rhocp*(DX/DT)*T(i);
    else
        A(i)= 0.75*rhocp*DX/DT + 2*k/dx;
        B(i)= k/dx;
        C(i)= k/dx;
        D(i)= rhocp*(DX/DT)*T(i);
    end

    P(1) = 0;
    Q(1) = T(1);
    for i = 2:L2
        DENO = A(i) - C(i)*P(i-1);
        NUM = D(i)+ C(i)*Q(i-1);
        P(i) = B(i)/DENO;
        Q(i) = NUM/DENO;
    end

    for i =L2:-1:2
        if i == L2
            T(i) = Q(i);
        else
            T(i) = P(i)*T(i+1) + Q(i);
        end
    end
    T(L1) = ((2*k*T(L2) - h*DX*Tinf)/(2*k - h*DX));
end
disp (T);
```

`

DENO and NUM is calculated as zero in the first iteration, even though on calculating their values is not zero! This leads to "Division by zero" error.

```
A(2)-C(2)*P(1)
```

ans  =

```
3750.
```

Analytically it has got a value though.

Answer (score 0):

Please give the parameter values so one can run your script...
DT was missing , i set it to 1 .

Finally I found the problem: you forgot an end to close  the loop
    for i = 2:L2
the end has to be put just before P(1)=0

Moreover this loop does not depend on the t value so it could be put before the loop for t = 0:300:3000

Comment: clc;
XL = 0.12;
DX = 0.03;
NCVLX = XL/DX;
L1 = NCVLX + 2;
L2 = L1 -1;
T = 85*ones(L1,1);
A = zeros(T);
B = zeros(T);
C = zeros(T);
D = zeros(T);
P = zeros(T);
Q = zeros(T);
XU(1) = 0.0;
XU(2) = 0.0;
dx = DX/2;
for i = 3:L2
    XU(i)= XU(i-1) + DX;
end

XU(L1) = XL;
X(1) = 0;
X(L1) = XU(L1);
for i = 2:L2
    X(i) = (XU(i)+XU(i+1))/2
end
   
h = 50;
k = 15;
rhocp = 10000000; 
Tinf = 20;  There you go, its the remaining part of the code.